# Derivation of form factors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

I want to derive the formal definition of the proton-proton-photon vertex:
[image]

The blob should be $\langle p^{+} p^{-}|J^{\mu}|\gamma^{*}\rangle$, where $J^{\mu}$ are the electromagnetic quark current in the Heisenberg Picture.

My starting point is working in the interaction picture and calculate the following matrix element:
\begin{equation}
    \langle p^{+} p^{-}|T\{ e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}+H_{QED,I}}\}|\gamma^{*}\rangle
\end{equation}
where the subscript $I$ refers to the QCD and QED Hamiltonian in the interaction picture. The QCD interaction is non-perturbative therefore there is no point to express it explicitly. The $H_{QED,I}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
   H_{QED,I}= eJ_{I}^{\mu}A_{I,\mu}:=e\bar{\psi}_I Q\psi_{I}\gamma^{\mu}A_{I,\mu}\psi
\end{equation}
where Q is the matrix representing electric charges of quarks and $\psi$ are quark fields. Taylor expanding  $e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}+H_{QED,I}}$ in terms of the electric charge gives
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\langle p^{+} p^{-}|T\{ e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}+H_{QED,I}}\}|\gamma^{*}\rangle\\
&= \langle p^{+} p^{-}|T\{ e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}} e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T} H_{QED,I}}\}|\gamma^{*}\rangle\\
&\approx \langle p^{+} p^{-}|T\{ e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}} (1-\int d^4x \,ieJ^{\mu}_I(x) A_{I,\mu})(x)\}|\gamma^{*}\rangle\\
&\approx \langle p^{+} p^{-}|T\{ e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}} (1-\int\, d^4x \, ieJ^{\mu}_I(x) A_{I,\mu}(x)\}|\gamma^{*}\rangle
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The next step is to contract the photon field $A_{I,\mu}(x)$ with the external virtual photon. My gut feeling is that after the Wick contraction the result should be
\begin{equation}
-\, ie\langle p^{+} p^{-}|T\{ e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}}\int\, d^4x J^{\mu}_I(x) \}|0\rangle\epsilon_{\mu}e^{-ipx}\,,
\end{equation}
My first question is how can one contract the photon fields without touching the stucture $e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}}$ and $J^{\mu}_I(x)$ in the time-ordering? If the final states were electrons and  $J^{\mu}_I(x)$ were electron currents, this is just wick contraction. But here we can't contract quark currents with the final state protons.

In many places (Peskin and A.Zee) one defines the form factor as the matrix element $\langle p^{+} p^{-}| J^{\mu}|0\rangle$, where $J^{\mu}$ I think should be in Heisenberg Picture. How do I get $\langle p^{+} p^{-}| J^{\mu} |0\rangle$ from $\langle p^{+} p^{-}|T\{ e^{-i\int_{-T}^{+T}H_{QCD,I}}\int\, d^4x J^{\mu}_I(x) \}|0\rangle$ where the fields are in interaction picture?